# Dynamically add an XML defined menu item

Tags: android, android-resources, android-library, android-menu

Assume we have a activity which is a child class of an activity defined in a library. In this child class, we want to add additional menu item into the menu created by the base class. But we want this additional menu item defined in XML. Is that possible? How?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    // TODO: how to add an additional menu item here?
    // the item is defined in xml
    // the id is item_switch_browsing_mode
    return true;
}

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_switch_browsing_mode"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try menu inflater, it should add menu items based on the specified xml, but call super.onCreateOptionsMenu to populate the parent menu items first. Something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();    
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.new_menu, menu);    
    return true;
}
```

You may refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuInflater.html.

Comment: Thanks, I just ignored this in the document "menu  The Menu to inflate into. The items and submenus will be added to this Menu.  " And I thought inflating will clear the base menu and create a new one.